# Setting parent window URL from a child window?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I am trying to do: Once submit a form on my main JSP/HTML page a new page with some link opens. When I click on any of the link the link should open in the parent Window. I.e the Window I started from. How do i do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use window.opener.location.href in javascript

For example,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.opener.location.href='linkedFile.html';">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need JavaScript for this. HTML's `target` can't target the window's parent (opener) window.

The following will open the page in the parent window if JavaScript is enabled, and open it in a new window if it is disabled. Also, it will react gracefully if the current page does not have an opener window.

```
<a href="page.php" 
   onclick="if (typeof window.opener != 'undefined')   // remove this line break
            window.opener.location.href = this.href; return false;"  
   target="_blank">
Click
</a>
```

[MDC Docs on window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.opener)

Comment: @nickf to prevent the page from opening in the current window if JS is disabled. That part is optional, but in many cases you won't want it replacing the current document

Comment: can't you set html's `target` to `_parent`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `parent.location.href` if it's on the same page in an iframe. Use `opener.location.href` if it's another entire tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.opener.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
```

This will reload the parent window once the URL(String) is assigned to the location.href.

Comment: How is this different from the already accepted answer from 2010?